# Unit test Scrapy parse function with inline_requests decorator

Tags: python, unit-testing, scrapy, pytest

I have a Scrapy Spider and it has a parse function which has `inline_requests` decorator, the inline request yields an item which is then combined to return the final output. Below is the code for reference -

```
@inline_requests
def parse(self, response):
    final_op = {}
    data = json.loads(response.body)
    body = {"id": data['id']}
    request_body = json.dumps(body)
    url = 'https://example.com'
    new_data = yield Request(url, method='POST', body=request_body)
    final_op['Name'] = data['Name value']
    final_op['other data'] = new_data['field']
    yield final_op
```

I want to Unit test this parse function and for that I need to mock the inline request. How can this be achieved? There is similar SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39733655/scrapy-effective-way-to-test-inline-requests) but that doesn't help.

Comment: Decorators are evaluated on import, so you have to make sure you mock it before importing your spider impl. But do you really need it? The [upstream tests](https://github.com/rmax/scrapy-inline-requests/blob/master/tests/test_inline_requests.py) are pretty much straightforward - prepare a `Response`, feed it to spider, validate the yielded `Request`s.

Comment: @hoefling Could you please provide a code example so that it becomes clearer. Also I referred the link you shared but that doesn't help.